# Is there any Android SMS app that prevents hyperlinks to be opened?

Tags: android, sms

My father has a Samsung Galaxy A6 phone running Android 8 or 9 (don't remember which on the top of my head). During the holiday season, there are a lot of scam SMS floating around containing hyperlinks to malicious websites. He has dementia and I'm afraid that he will click on one of these hyperlinks.

I periodically remote connect to his phone, removing any scam SMS messages I can see, but I would like to be able to prevent URL's from opening from SMS messages overall. He rarely use SMS, so he wouldn't need to be able to open legitimate websites that way. I don't want to remove the web browser on his phone, because he uses it every day to access his favourite websites.

I have tried a couple of SMS apps, but none of them seem to support blocking the launch of a browser. I don't want to root my father's phone, because I feel that would probably create more problems than it would solve.

Of course, I could delve into the source code of Android's stock SMS app and try to change the behaviour of hyperlinks, but I'd much rather just use an existing app.

The app doesn't have to be free. Suggestions for paid apps are also welcome.

Comment: SMS ist just plain text. For making clickable links the app has to parse the text and scan for http(s) links. I would check very simple SMS apps and open source apps. If none supports to disable clickable links consider asking for such an option.

Comment: Related on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/243138/44325